# Update path of existing SVG element

Tags: svg

I am trying to draw a border on `svg` element using code.

```
 elem.attr({
                    'stroke-width' : 2,
                    'stroke' : '#3fa9f5'
                });
```

elem is already drawn and I dont have control how its drawn . When I see its path  ie `elem.d`  , Z is not present at end. Because of that I am not able to draw border at one end.

```
elem.d="M 323.5 8 L 323.5 40 409.5 40 409.5 8"
```

Can I dynamically add Z to the above element? Adding Z to elem.d string is not working.

Code for adding Z to elem.d

```
if(elem.d !== undefined){
                if(elem.d.indexOf("Z") === -1){
                    elem.d += " Z";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no [elem.d property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData). The interface is SVGAnimatedPathData

So it's [elem[0].pathSegList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement).appendItem to append the Z. And [createSVGPathSegClosePath](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegClosePath) to create it which means putting it all together looks like this.

```
elem[0].pathSegList.appendItem(elem[0].createSVGPathSegClosePath());
```

The [0] unwraps the jquery wrapper on the element (if elem is a raw DOM element object then the [0] is not necessary)

If you want to test whether the last segment is a close path then you want something like this...

```
var pathSegList = elem[0].pathSegList;
if (pathSegList.numberOfItems > 0) {
    var lastSeg = pathSegList.getItem(pathSegList.numberOfItems - 1);
    if (lastSeg.pathSegType != lastSeg.PATHSEG_CLOSEPATH) {
       // do whatever
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could do with with attr (jquery) or get/setAttribute (DOM)

elem.attr(d) will get the attribute as a string as will elem[0].getAttribute("d") The SVG DOM above will give better perfomance though.

Comment: How to check if closedpath is already added? I am seeing lots of Z's in svg outerHTML